# css rule names in makeStyles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Instead of having

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    PopoverRoot: {
        textAlign: "center",
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    PopoverPaper: {
        padding: '1em',
    },
    OtherStyles: {
        //...
    }
});

function foo() {
    classes = useStyles();
    return(
        <Popover classes={classes.Popover}>...</Popover>
        <Something classes={classes.OtherStyles}>...</Something>
    )
}
```

I would like to have something nested, like this

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    Popover: {
        root: {
            textAlign: "center",
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
        },
        paper: {
            padding: '1em',
        },
    },

    OtherStyles: {
        //...
    }
});

function foo() {
    classes = useStyles();
    return(
        <Popover classes={classes.Popover}>...</Popover>
        <Something classes={classes.OtherStyles}>...</Something>
    )
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. First of all React complained about using `classes` instead of `className`, so I changed that then. The problem is, the styles are not applied this way.

How to achieve that?

Comment: can you show the bit of code where you use the useStyles function (hook) ?

Comment: Have you checked the docs on this ? https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api

Comment: @Apolo, sure - added it above

Answer (score -1):

First you have to define classes.

```
const classes = useStyles()
```

And then use them:

```
<Popover className={classes.Popover}>...</Popover>
```